# EL Attribute not printing

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored=false %>

${msg}`
```

Am trying to print the message using EL but when the page loads, its getting displayed AS IS

Am using WAS6.1 (web-app -2_3) - Java5

Regards

Comment: What do you mean "its getting displayed AS IS"? You mean the MSG ONLY OR whole jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve it ...

Answering it for the benefit of others

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

The attribute has to be within quotes - "" for it to be working